# A relative path inside INCLUDEPICTURE field changes to absolute path sometimes somehow

Tags: ms-word

When I use a relative path in an INCLUDEPICTURE field, sometimes somehow it changes to an absolute path automatically.

```
Before:
   {INCLUDEPICTURE  ".\\img\\TEST_01.png" \d  \* MERGEFORMAT}

After:
   {INCLUDEPICTURE  "c:\\test\\img\\TEST_01.png" \d  \* MERGEFORMAT}
```

Please let me know why and how to avoid this. I want to make links to image files in a sub folder.

Answer (score 2):

Although you've tried to make the path relative by omitting some of it, it nevertheless remains absolute. To make the path behave in a truly relative manner, you need to employ a FILENAME field, thus:

```
{INCLUDEPICTURE "{FILENAME \p}/../Image.png"}
```

or

```
{INCLUDEPICTURE "{FILENAME \p}\\..\\Image.png"}
```

How this works: The FILENAME p field extracts the current file's name and path. The following '\\..\\' or '/../' tells Word to ignore the filename and get just the path. Then all you need to do is to add the source file's name & extension.

The same approach can be extended to implement a form of relative addressing. For example:

```
{INCLUDEPICTURE "{FILENAME \p}\\..\\My Pictures\\Image.png"}
```

looks in the child folder named 'My Pictures' and:

```
{INCLUDEPICTURE "{FILENAME \p}\\..\\..\\Image.png"}
```

looks in the parent folder, while:

```
{INCLUDEPICTURE "{FILENAME \p}\\..\\..\\My Pictures\\Image.png"}
```

looks in the parent folder, then its child folder named 'My Pictures' (a sibling folder, so to speak).

**Note:** You can go down the file tree by adding however many sets of '\\..\\' you need, but you must give explicit folder names for navigating back up it.

Comment: Thank you for the solution. I'll test it. By the way, as far as I tested, the links act as relative links until they are converted to absolute links. The behavior seems not stable about this.

Comment: The only links that would be converted to absolute via this technique are if you try to use it with LINK fields, but the discussion here concerned only INCLUDEPICTURE fields. Of course, if you unlink the FILENAME field, you can't expect the solution to work as you'll have destroyed the very feature that made it all possible.

Answer (score 0):

A relative path is retained if `MERGEFORMAT` does not appear in the field code or is replaced by `MERGEFORMATINET`. The latter switch doesn't change even if you save, close and reopen the file. So in your case use

```
{ INCLUDEPICTURE  ".\\img\\TEST_01.png" \d  \* MERGEFORMATINET }
```

or

```
{ INCLUDEPICTURE  ".\\img\\TEST_01.png" \d  }
```